# Jsoup: select(div[class=rslt prod]) returns null when it shouldn't

Tags: java, select, jsoup

I am trying to select the all div with class="rlts prod" from this page http://www.amazon.fr/s/field-keywords=samsung

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.amazon.fr/s/field-keywords=samsung").get();
Elements divProd = doc.select("div[class=rslt prod]");      
System.out.println("\nsize: "+divProd.size());
```

But it returns 0 and it shouldn't, any idea why ?

example of what should be selected:

```
<div id="result_4" class="rslt prod" name="B006O9QNHU">
[...]
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the *user agent*, otherwise you get a differnt website from amazon.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.amazon.fr/s/field-keywords=samsung")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/17.0") // you can use any other user agent here
        .get();

for( Element element : doc.select("div[class=rslt prod]") )
{
    System.out.println(element);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Now the output is a list like

```
<div id="result_1" class="rslt prod" name="B007XOM6SU"> 
  ...
</div>

<div id="result_2" class="rslt prod" name="B006SXSF4Q"> 
  ...
</div>

...
```