# JSOUP throws url status 503 in Eclipse but URL works fine in browser

Tags: java, jsoup

In particular, this is with the website amazon.com to be specific. I am receiving a 503 error for their domain, but I can successfully parse other domains.

I am using the line

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(30000).get();
```

to connect to the URL.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set a *User Agent*:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(30000).userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();
```

*(Or others; best you choose a browser user agent)*

Else you'll get blocked.

Please see also: [Jsoup: select(div[class=rslt prod]) returns null when it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367765/jsoup-selectdivclass-rslt-prod-returns-null-when-it-shouldnt/15384490#15384490)

Comment: well, I ran the program on my laptop and it ran without a problem. I then subsequently ran it on my desktop (where the problem originated) with no problem at all. I tried your fix and it told me "please supply a valid URL". Thanks for your attempt, but it didn't seem to be the answer to my problem.

Comment: How is this told - exception or by the website? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: throws an exception in the java console; the code is surrounded by a try/catch statement. Sorry, I can't really recreate the error now :( Next time I run into it I will try these answers and post about which one worked. I have a feeling it had to do w/ my IP. I was tethered when I ran into it, tried it on wifi at a restaurant and it worked, now it works while on tethered again.

Comment: If you get an exception the next time, please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
val ret=Jsoup.connect(url)
  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31")
  .timeout(2*1000)
  .followRedirects(true)
  .maxBodySize(1024*1024*3)    //3Mb Max
  //.ignoreContentType(true) //for download xml, json, etc
  .get()
```

it maybe works, maybe amazon.com need followRedirects set to true.

Comment: Timeout is set to `3000` and `followRedirects` to `true` per default.